# Load image over socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm currently receiving text:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    try
    {
        int received = _clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);

        //string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer);
        Array.Resize(ref _buffer, received);
        //AppendToTextBox(text);
        Array.Resize(ref _buffer, _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        _clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

How can I read an image, instead of text?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to wait to receive the entire thing, and then:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(entireBuffer)) {
    var image = Image.FromStream(ms);

    // Go ahead and put it in a PictureBox now
}
```

Comment: thank you.but now it is saying "parameter is not valid" i m gonna write every codes.in other question